# AngularDart RouteData not available

Tags: dart, angular-routing, angular-dart

I'm trying to receive RouteData in my component, but it isn't working like I'd expect. The message I receive is: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid argument(s): No provider found for RouteData.`

Pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0
  angular_components: ^0.8.0
  angular_router: ^1.0.2
```

main.dart:

```
void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    const Provider(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy),
  ]);
}
```

my component:

```
@RouteConfig(
  const [
    const Route(
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        useAsDefault: true,
        data: const {
          'title': 'Page Title',
        }),
  ],
)
class AppComponent {
  final Router _router;
  final RouteData _routeData;
  AppComponent(this._router, this._routeData);
}
```

Is there something I'm obviously doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add data to the `Home` route, you can only inject it to the `HomeComponent`. You can use a globally shared service to make it available elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Oh I see... that makes sense. Thanks!